# "New York is raining" vs "It is raining in New York"

Tags: grammar, usage

> New York is raining.
>
> It is raining in New York.

Which one is correct?

As far as I learned, it is correct to use *it* to describe weather. 
However, is it possible to say *New York is raining* in colloquial English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'It is raining'  or 'It's raining'  are the usual ways to say this.

However, you can get creative and say that a person, place or thing is raining. This can be figurative, as in

'Bob is raining on my parade' (= Bob is ruining my activity.)

or more to do with actual rain:

'New York is raining cats and dogs this morning' (= It's raining cats and dogs in New York this morning.) Here we are ascribing to New York the weather in New York in a substitution of the noun *New York* for the *impersonal it* that we usually use. You won't hear this often, but perhaps on the weather station.

Answer (score 4):

Only the latter, "It is raining in New York" works. New York is raining would not work and is the equivalent of saying, Bob is raining. New York is a state/city and cannot perform the verb rain.

Answer (score 1):

"It is raining in New York" or " New York is getting drenched in rain " would work.

you can refer to 
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192296/can-i-use-drenching-to-mean-being-drenched for the latter case

Comment: You can't use "getting drenched" as a general replacement for "it is raining". "Raining" is a neutral term that covers everything from drizzle to tropical downpour, and only refers to the immediate present, whereas "getting drenched" indicates heavy rain and adds a sense of prolonged rain as well.